# Toggling between Menu Active states using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
    $("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
      $("ul.menu li a").removeClass("currentMenu");
      $(this).addClass("currentMenu");
    });
```

At page startup, my "Home" menu button is set to "currentMenu", which basically has a color background set to orange.

What I am trying to achieve, which the above jQuery code doesn't cater for is if I click on the existing "Home" button that is set to "currentMenu", I actually would like to remove this class, so the "Home" button no longer has the orange background color and vice-versa, when "Home" button unset, then set to "currentmenu" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out the *current* element then [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), like this:

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
  $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("currentMenu");
  $(this).toggleClass("currentMenu");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/6NX85/), this just filters the clicked anchor out of the collection so it won't be affected by the [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) then does [`.toggleClasss()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to give the toggle on/off effect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function() {

  if ($(this).is(".currentMenu")) {
    $(this).removeClass("currentMenu");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("currentMenu");
  }

  $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("currentMenu");
});
```